# Uploading file in ruby rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to upload a file and save at a specific path. I use following code to do the same.

In my view I use file_field tag

```
<%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile', {:value => @original_file_name} %>
```

controller

```
xmlfilepath = DataFile.save(params[:upload][:datafile],@xml_file)
```

Model

```
def self.save(file_handle,file_name)
    File.open(file_name, "wb") { |f| f.write(file_handle.read) }
end
```

But on upload I'm getting following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `read' for "thorConfig_2013_11_27_06_52_05.xml":String):
```

I could not find out how to resolve this error. I would be glad if any one can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest implementing something like this for security purposes of the path 
(uses `paperclip` gem) [link](http://makandracards.com/makandra/734-deliver-paperclip-attachments-to-authorized-users-only)

or implement with a similar logic

hope it helps.

as for your error, make sure you have `multipart: true` on your form.
the error says that "I can't read the object, either its null or empty

try adding

```
if file_handle.blank?
  File.open(file_name, "wb") { |f| f.write(file_handle.read) }
end
```

Comment: You were right I missed out multipart: true in the form tag. Including it fixed the error.